# blender crashes at rendering with random textures

Tags: rendering, texturing, scripting, random

I want to render a file with different textures in the background. The background is a particle system which has about 500 particles per frame. The objects are only Mesh objects you can add in Blender (cubes, uv-Sphere, cones for example) but all different in scaling ( important for my scenario). The textures should change every fifth frame randomly. The texturesize is only 0.5K.  If I run the code and start rendering blender crashes at frame 6. I have no idea how I have to change my code or my Blender settings to render my file without a crash. On this frame the window "3D" in "Task Manager" Peaks and Blender closed.

Hardware:
Win 10;
Intel I7 - 10850;
Nvidia Quatro RTX 3000;
32 GB DDR4

```
import random
import bpy
import sys    
import time 

prefix = 'BG'

def run_script(scene):
    
    frame_num = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

    if frame_num % 5== 0:

        materials = []
        for mat in bpy.data.materials:

            if mat.name.startswith(prefix):
                materials.append(mat)
                
        for obj in bpy.data.collections['background'].all_objects:
            obj.select_set(True)
            obj.active_material = random.choice(materials)
                
bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(run_script)
```

If I start Blender in the background to safe some hardware capacity I don't know how to start the skript wrote in the Blender editor. I use this path and enable "Auto run python scripts" but it doesn't run the material script.
commands:

```
<filepath of Blender 3.3>blender.exe -b <filepath of blender file> -a
```

Thank you Community.

Scene: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05QBe.jpg

Comment: Can't reproduce that. can you share the scene?

Comment: I mean blend file

Comment: I hope i upload it correctly but i had to reduce some objects because of the data size.

Comment: At list, it is a first step - get the minimum example where the issue occurs. You can post it in bug tracker if it is really bug.

Comment: problem solved - minimal number of objects and increasing the number of textures which are choose randomly get the same results i want to.